# run program with a directory viewed with a different name

Tags: unix

Is there a way to run a run a program, and only for that run it sees some directory with a different name than its original one?, for example:

There is a directory with a name: /home/user/somedir

But we run something like: 
$diralias --original /home/user/somedir --alias /home/user/somedir2 myProgram

so that 'myProgram' sees '/home/user/somedir' as '/home/user/somedir2'.

also, there is already a directory named 'somedir2', but the alias should have precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ln command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln) like this to create symbolic links in Unix:

```
ln -s somedir somedir-alias
```

Comment: I forgot the part where there is already a directory named as the alias.

Comment: I don't get this line from your question: `there is already a directory named 'somedir2', but the alias should have precedence`

Comment: it means that when myProgram tries to access 'somedir2', it should access the alias, not the real directory.